# Should "hens" (as in a hen party) be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

"Love from your hens" or "Love from your Hens". Unsure of weather to capitalize the word hens when discussing a group of girls from a hen party.

Comment: Presumably the context is informal, so it really doesn't matter; go with whichever looks right to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these girls are all part of an established, known and defined group, then **Hens** is fine. [groups](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-10/capitalization/lesson-4/names-of-groups-of-people)

If the girls are only casually associated, then **hens**.

If this is a case of informal writing, either would be OK.  **Hens** could be used for impact, or, humor.

In formal writing, capitalization should only be used if the girls go by the collective name **Hens.**  If there is any doubt about the suitability of capitalization, **"Hens"**   should placed in quotation marks  [Highlighting certain words](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Quotation-Marks.htm).

So

> Love from your **Hens** (informally, if the receiver will understand who the girls are, or for impact)
>
> Love from your **hens** (if who the girls are wouldn't be known exactly)
>
> Love from your **hens** (formally, if the girls are not a known group)
>
> Love from your **Hens** (formally, if there is no doubt the group of girls is known and established as **Hens**)
>
> Love from your **"Hens"** (formally, if there is doubt that the girls in the group are firmly known as **Hens**)

Comment: Hello just to clarify when you say known do you mean to the reader (The Bride/bride...not again, who's hens they are) or just in general. They wouldn't normally go by the name hens and nor would they be known as hens to many people so i'm thinking hens not Hens.

Comment: @user2135854  known to the reader . My assumption is that this is involves a private communication, whether part of a larger narrative, or not.